# gRPC - Accessing headers in async communication

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I have a kubernetes cluster where there are microservices running.
When I call Java based microservice, the Spring boot application receives all the HTTP requests, internally calls another backend service as a gRPC request, gets response then returns http response back to user. This is similar to how typically a distributed systems would work.

Call to gRPC backend is made using Future.callback() method.

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    Futures.addCallback(listenableFuture, new FutureCallback<ResponseType>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(ResponseType result) {
        
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        
      }
    }, executorService);
```

Since Futures.addCallback is used, the response will be received by any of the available threads in executorService.

Before making gRPC request, I set few headers in the context.
With this kind of setup, whenever i receive the response from backend grpc service, I want to access some of header fields which was set by server earlier.
The thread in the executorService which receives backend gRPC response doesnt not have context from server which was set earlier.

Is there a mechanism using which I can access server headers, when the response comes back ?

I tried using Context.Key, but it does not work since it uses reference equality. This information is lost, since the thread is different.

Comment: @eric-anderson any idea about this?

Comment: Could you add the header data in the request, and have the server return them to you in the response?

Comment: Why not just make a Unary call and skip the threading. gRpc is fast. Since you never context switch your headers are still right there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Context.fixedContextExecutor](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Context.html#fixedContextExecutor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-):

> wrap an Executor so that it always executes with this context as the **current()** context.